# AS3 - How do you wait for a tween inside a for loop to complete?

Tags: actionscript-3, for-loop, gsap

I'm drawing a large shape using an array of points in a for loop and tweenlite as found at http://www.flashperfection.com/tutorials/Animated-line-drawing-using-TweenLite-in-AS3-22013.html

```
for(var i:uint = 0; i < pointsArray.length; i++){
TweenLite.to(dot2, .05, {x:pointsArray[i].x,
  y:pointsArray[i].y,
  delay:i*.05,
  overwrite:false,
 onUpdate:updateHandler});
}
function updateHandler():void{
lineAnim.graphics.lineTo(dot2.x, dot2.y);
lineAnim.graphics.moveTo(dot2.x, dot2.y);
}
```

I would like the animation to complete before continuing, but I'm unable to find a way to be notified when the full animation is complete.  onComplete does not work as it triggers on the first set of coords.  I also tried triggering when

```
i == pointsArray.length
```

but the loop finishes multiple seconds before the animation completes.  I would like to avoid using a timer.

Comment: You need to approach the problem a different way. In Actionscript, code executes between the rendering process. Your loop needs to finish for the user to be able to see anything, so you'll have to use an event listener or a callback.

Comment: The callback didn't work, but your comment to approach the problem in a different way did!  Instead of waiting for the animation to finish I wait until dot2 gets to the final coords.  `if(dot2.x == 460 && dot2.y == 440){myFunction();}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do an asynchronous loop by doing something like the following:

```
var curIndex:int = 0; //a var to hold the current index of the points array
tweenItem();

//a function to call every time a tween is finished
function tweenItem(){
    if(curIndex >= pointsArray.length){
        //all done, do something
        return;
    }

    TweenLite.to(dot2, .05, {
        x:pointsArray[curIndex].x,
        y:pointsArray[curIndex].y,
        onUpdate:updateHandler,
        onComplete: tweenItem //call this function again once the tween completes
    });

    curIndex++; //incriment the index
}
```

---

Now,  you could save yourself the trouble and just use [TimelineLite](http://greensock.com/timelinelite), made by the same author, which makes sequencing multiple tweens very easy.

Comment: Thank you - TimelineLite is what I needed. :)

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, you need to use a callback.

I'm not too familiar with TweenLite, but can you add the onComplete callback to the last call only? Something like this:

```
for(var i:uint = 0; i < pointsArray.length; i++){
    var extraArguments:Object = {
        x:pointsArray[i].x,
        y:pointsArray[i].y,
        delay:i*.05,
        overwrite:false,
        onUpdate:updateHandler
    };
    // add in the onComplete callback only if it's the last loop.
    if (i == pointsArray.length - 1 ) {
        extraArguments.onComplete = yourOnCompleteFunction;
    }
    TweenLite.to(dot2, .05, extraArguments);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this had no effect.  The loop seems to run through the entire array immediately, not waiting for the delay of each tween, so the loop completes before the animation completes.